Prevent Insert in stored procedure from being rolled back by caller
I created a stored procedure with an insert like this:
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
    @Param1 varchar(50)
    @Param2 varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    
    INSERT INTO MyTable 
        @Param1
        @Param2

        Do some more stuff here
END

So now MyProcedure is called by another procedure somewhat like this:
BEGIN TRANSACTION

do some stuff ....

EXECUTE @return_value = MyProcedure

do some more stuff ...

IF(@return_value < 0)
BEGIN
   ROLLBACK
END

With this setup, if there is an error in MyProcedure the rollback is executed and my insert is also rolled back. The INSERT should save what data was given to MyProcedure.
I don't know who is going to call MyProcedure in the future so it would be great to make sure that my INSERT is really happening even if the caller is doing a rollback. Is there anything i can do ?

Not much you can do, unless you manipulate the caller procedure. Well, you can stop returning errors, but that might not be feasable. Do the log outside of your procedure, if you need to keep it around, or move the transaction handling inside the procedure

This is an XY Problem - you have a problem X (tracing calls for debugging? auditing? something else?) and assume Y, a simple INSERT, is the solution. When that fails, you ask about Y, not the actual problem. Why do you want a kind of a log ? There are tracing and auditing features already that offer far more scalable solutions. For example, Extended Events are a lightweight way to capture what you want

@PanagiotisKanavos It's not a real Log. The procedure takes some params that i just want to save to a table even if there is a rollback.

I guess i have to talk to my colleague that is calling my procedure ...

Do you want to entirely prevent that rollback? Meaning what about things that the outer proc wants to roll back?

@Charlieface No, I just want to prevent my insert from being rolled back

You have 2 goal but 1 transaction. They are conflicted.
You need to call MyProcedure from outside of the Transaction statement.
Loging is a separate process. Procedure call either failed or succes you need to record. So separate 2 process.
First call logging procedure with working params, without explicit transaction  statement.
Then call actual transaction process.
EXECUTE @return_value = MyProcedure   -- first process

BEGIN TRANSACTION    -- second process

do some stuff ....

-- EXECUTE @return_value = MyProcedure  remove this line

do some more stuff ...

IF(@return_value < 0)
BEGIN
   ROLLBACK
END

or you can modify the code like
EXECUTE @return_value = MyProcedure   -- first process
 IF(@return_value > 0)
   BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION    
    
    do some stuff ....
    
           
    do some more stuff ...
    
    END 
END


Wouldn't that process the work twice on success?

Yes, it would, @siggemannen .

I suggested 'Loging is a separate process. Procedure call either failed or succes you need to record. So separate 2 process.'
after seperation why would work twice

Yes in this case MyProcedure would be executed twice. Did you mean to first do the Log-Process and then the normal procedure?

I comment the dublicate line. Make 2 separate process. Second process is using as a condition of @return_value of first process. Then you will achieve your 2 goal.
